# Python Rotate object with non uniform scale on local axis

Tags: python

How can I rotate an object with non uniform scale on the local axis.
When the object has a random scale(5,23,12), the rotation is either way off or it slightly jitters.

When it has a uniform scale(1,1,1), I can just do:

```
import bpy
from math import floor,ceil,sqrt,log10,radians,degrees,cos,sin,pi
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Euler

object_x = bpy.context.active_object

rot_matrix = Euler((radians(25),0,0)).to_matrix().to_4x4()
object_x.matrix_local = object_x.matrix_local  * rot_matrix

# Trigger UI Update
bpy.context.scene.update() 
object_x.location = object_x.location
```

Comment: You might need to apply the scale see [Question 7298](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)